# best way to fill up gaps by yearly dates in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

all, I'm newbie to Python and am stuck with the problem below. I have a DF as:

ipdb> DF

```
    asofdate  port_id
1 2010-01-01       76
2 2010-04-01       43
3 2011-02-01       76
4 2013-01-02       93
5 2017-02-01       43
```

For the yearly gaps, say 2012, 2014, 2015, and 2016, I'd like to fill in the gap using the new year date for each of the missing years, and port_id from previous year.  Ideally, I'd like:

ipdb> DF

```
    asofdate  port_id
1 2010-01-01       76
2 2010-04-01       43
3 2011-02-01       76
4 2012-01-01       76
5 2013-01-02       93
6 2014-01-01       93
7 2015-01-01       93
8 2016-01-01       93
9 2017-02-01       43
```

I tried multiple approaches but still no avail.  Could some expert shed me some lights on how to make it work out?  Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Thanks much, sacul, for correcting the format for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set.difference` with `range` to find missing dates and then append a dataframe:

```
# convert to datetime if not already converted
df['asofdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['asofdate'])

# calculate missing years
years = df['asofdate'].dt.year
missing = set(range(years.min(), years.max())) - set(years)

# append dataframe, sort and front-fill
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'asofdate': pd.to_datetime(list(missing), format='%Y')}))\
       .sort_values('asofdate')\
       .ffill()

print(df)

    asofdate  port_id
1 2010-01-01     76.0
2 2010-04-01     43.0
3 2011-02-01     76.0
1 2012-01-01     76.0
4 2013-01-02     93.0
2 2014-01-01     93.0
3 2015-01-01     93.0
0 2016-01-01     93.0
5 2017-02-01     43.0
```

Comment: Thanks much, jpp, for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `helper` dataframe, containing all the year start dates, then filter out the ones where the years match what is in `df`, and finally merge them together:

```
# First make sure it is proper datetime
df['asofdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.asofdate)

# Create your temporary dataframe of year start dates
helper = pd.DataFrame({'asofdate':pd.date_range(df.asofdate.min(), df.asofdate.max(), freq='YS')})

# Filter out the rows where the year is already in df
helper = helper[~helper.asofdate.dt.year.isin(df.asofdate.dt.year)]

# Merge back in to df, sort, and forward fill
new_df = df.merge(helper, how='outer').sort_values('asofdate').ffill()

>>> new_df
    asofdate  port_id
0 2010-01-01     76.0
1 2010-04-01     43.0
2 2011-02-01     76.0
5 2012-01-01     76.0
3 2013-01-02     93.0
6 2014-01-01     93.0
7 2015-01-01     93.0
8 2016-01-01     93.0
4 2017-02-01     43.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance today, sacul, greatly appreciated!